# R, Polyclip, intersecting edges

Tags: r

I am using the `polyclip` library, and need to get, from a polygon (intersection between two polygons, A and B), the edges of this polygon that lie within A, but not on the edges of B.

For example, the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(polyclip)
A <- list(list(x=c(.1,.1,.9,.9),y=c(.1,.9,.9,.1)))
B <- list(list(x=c(0,.5,1),y=c(0,sqrt(3)/2,0)))
C <- polyclip(A, B)
close = function(x){
  rbind(x,x[1,])
}
getDataStruct <- function(x){
  close(data.frame(x=x[[1]]$x,y=x[[1]]$y))  
}
ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(data=getDataStruct(A),fill="red",alpha=.5) + 
  geom_polygon(data=getDataStruct(B),fill="green",alpha=.5) + 
  geom_polygon(data=getDataStruct(C),color="magenta",size=2,fill="magenta",alpha=.5)
```

Generates the following image:

[image: Example]

If we say that in the above, let the red square be A, the green triangle be B, and the magenta shape be C, as the intersection of A and B. What I need to extract are the small left vertical, small right vertical and long bottom horizontal edges from C, whilst discarding the top angled and right angled edge of the magenta shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workflow using the `rgeos` library would simply convert the A polygon object to a line and then take the intersection with the B polygon. The resulting line object contains your edges of interest.

```
library(rgeos)

A <- readWKT("LINESTRING(0.1 0.1, 0.9 0.1, 0.9 0.9, 0.1 0.9, 0.1 0.1)")
B <- readWKT("POLYGON((0 0, 0.5 0.8660254, 1 0, 0 0))")

plot(B,col='green')
plot(A,add=TRUE)

#now taking the intersection
C <- gIntersection(B,A)
plot(C,col='blue',add=TRUE,lwd=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The C-object is a list with two vectors x and y inside an outer (single) list. Presumably, this is done so there can be multiple "intersections".

```
> str(C)
List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ x: num [1:5] 0.9 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.9
  ..$ y: num [1:5] 0.173 0.866 0.173 0.1 0.1
```

So by inspection of the graphic, a fairly simple test of the points that are wanted, is that the y values be less than 0.5. So set that apex value to NA.

```
> sC2 <- C[[1]]    # just get the inner list
# now set the xa nd y values to NA if the Y values are greater than 0.5
> sC2 <- lapply(sC2 , function(x) {is.na(x) <- sC2$y > .5; x})
> sC2
$x
[1] 0.9  NA 0.1 0.1 0.9

$y
[1] 0.173    NA 0.173 0.100 0.100
```